# Llenado de una matriz a partir de un arreglo en C

Tags: c, vscode

Llenar una matriz con la cantidad de veces que se repite una vocal de una palabra y que vocal son los que contiene la frase.

Ejemplo de impresión:
2[a][a]
1[e]

Cree un arreglo donde contiene las vocales que tiene la palabra, y hice una variable donde guarde el número de veces que se repite cada vocal, después mediante un arreglo guarde cada vocal y lo hice igual al número de vocales que contiene la palabra, pero antes de pasar al arreglo que guarde las veces que se repite cada vocal intente hacer el guardado de las vocales.

El arreglo fue el char vocales_palabra[tamaño], donde el tamaño fue la cantidad de vocales(a,e,i,o,u nadamas solo contando 1 solo).

Que en el caso de la palabra : pajaro deberia guardar [a],[o], pero al momento de yo implementarlo en un if() solo guarda dos veces [o].

Adjunto el código y no se si hay otra forma menos extensa de hacerlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>  

int main()
{
  char frase[30];
  int total_vocales=0,numero_vocales=0,vocal_a=0,vocal_e=0,vocal_i=0,vocal_o=0,vocal_u=0;
  printf("Escriba una palabra:");
  scanf("%s",&frase);

    for(int i=0;i<=frase[i];i++){
      switch (frase[i])
      {
        case 'a': vocal_a++;total_vocales++; 
        break;
        case 'e': vocal_e++;total_vocales++; 
        break;
        case 'i': vocal_i++;total_vocales++; 
        break;
        case 'o': vocal_o++;total_vocales++; 
        break;
        case 'u': vocal_u++;total_vocales++; 
        break;
      }
    }
  
  if(0<vocal_a)
  {
    numero_vocales++;
  }
  if(0<vocal_e)
  {
    numero_vocales++;
  }
  if(0<vocal_i)
  {
    numero_vocales++;
  }
  if(0<vocal_o)
  {
    numero_vocales++;
  }
  if(0<vocal_u)
  {
    numero_vocales++;
  }
  int tamaño= numero_vocales;

  char vocales_palabra[tamaño];
  for (int s = 0; s<tamaño ; s++)
  {
    if(vocal_a>0)
    {
      vocales_palabra[s]='a';
    }
    if(vocal_e>0)
    {
      vocales_palabra[s]='e';
    }
    if(vocal_i>0)
    {
      vocales_palabra[s]='i';
    }
    if(vocal_o>0)
    {
      vocales_palabra[s]='o';
    }
    if(vocal_u>0)
    {
     vocales_palabra[s]='u';
    }
  }
  for(int j=0;j<vocales_palabra[j];j++)
  {
    printf("[%c]",vocales_palabra[j]);
  }
}
```

Nota: Aun no pongo la matriz que guardara las variables.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas primero voy a resumir tu código usando arreglos, veo que estas empezando c voy a tener una gran paciencia : ).

**Problemas**:

1- La función scanf solo te almacenará una palabra, la solución es pasar este argumento `%[^\n]s` en lugar de este `%s`

2- Las letras `ñ` no se pueden usar en variables.

3- Piensas que los arreglos te entregaran sus tamaños solo con usar el elemento actual: `for (int i=0;i<frase[i];i++){...}`(Las cadenas no son mas que arreglo de chars), `for (int j=0;j<vocales_palabra[j];j++){...}`. Esto es un problema porque:

- La cadena: `for (int i=0;i<frase[i];i++){...}`: Cada char tiene un valor(dependiendo de la codificación que esta usando el compilador)(El entandar es [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) que es muy parecido al UTF-8(sin boom)). Y ese valor es evaluado cuando haces `i<frase[i]`. Vamos a suponer que ingresas por la consola esta frase: hello. Veamos que sucede con cada iteracion:

  - 0<'h'(h en ASCII es 104): true
  - 1<'e'(............  101): true
  - 2<'l'(............  108): true
  - 3<'l'(............  108): true
  - 4<'o'(............  111): true
  - 5<'\0'(NULL)(.....  0): false
    Por lo visto te funciona, pero vamos a suponer que la cadena tenga mas de 150(Ya no seria entrada por el teclado, sino un archivo) y en la posición 50 te consigues con un '0'(48) en este caso perderás todos los caracteres desde la posición 50 hasta 150(Seria 100 caracteres perdidos), aquí ya no se vuelve fiable este método o en la posición 10 te consigue con el HT(Tab. horizontal) y como la cadena tiene 150 caracteres perderemos 140 caracteres por lo que ya no sirve este metodo(Nota: Si lo usas puede que el profesor te embrome y coloque una cadena larga y en la mitad un carácter de bajo tamaño para que falle tu función). Para solucionar esto usaremos la función `strlen(const char*);` que debes incluir este encabezado `include <string.h>`, strlen te retorna el tamaño de la cadena completa(Un bucle que aumenta una cuenta hasta que se consigue el caracter NULL y retorna la cuenta) o también podemos hacer(Experimental(no le veo fallo, pero no significa que no los tenga y digo experimental porque no lo he usado nunca este método, no por el compilador)) `for(int i=0;frase[i]!=0;i++){...}`.
    En las cadenas uno o el compilador tenemos la obligación de colocar un caracter NULLO al final de la cadena(Cuando haces `char* a="hola";` el compilador le agrega el carácter nulo automáticamente), si no se coloca puede salir caracteres extraños en la función printf(intenta: `char hola[4]={'h','o','l','a'};printf("La cadena es: %s",hola);`) o errores inesperados en otras funciones.
- El arreglo de enteros `for(int j=0;j<vocales_palabra[j];j++)`: Solo las cadenas tienen el carácter NULLO para marcar un limite, con los demas arrays debes conocer el tamaño: `for(int j=0;j<tamaño;j++)`.

**Primero:** haces código innecesario: `vocal_a,..., vocal_u;`  en lugar de usar tantas variables puedes usar un arreglo de 5 elementos:

```
int vocales[]={'A','E','I','O','U'};
char vocales_cant[]={0,0,0,0,0};//Creamos el arreglo he inicializamos todas las posiciones en 0 para efectuar la cuenta.
```

**Segundo:** Al tener un arreglo que tendrá la cantidad de todas las vocales, podemos jugar con el:

```
for(int i=0;i<=frase[i];i++){
    for (int vocal=0;vocal<MAX_VOCALS;vocal++){
        if (vocales[vocal]==frase[i] || vocales[vocal]+32==frase[i]){//Recuerda que usamos ASCII
            vocales_cant[vocal]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Dicho todo ahora vamos con el código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>//Para tu codigo conio no es necesario y también hoy en día es obsoleta, por lo que no lo debes aprender.
#define MAX_VOCALS 5
int main()
{
    char frase[30];
    char vocales[]={'A','E','I','O','U'};
    char output[MAX_VOCALS*2+1];
    int vocales_cant[]={0,0,0,0,0};//A-U hay 5 vocales.
    int total_vocales=0;
    printf("Escriba una palabra:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&frase);//%[^\n]s para leer la frase completa hasta un salto de linea.

    for(int i=0;i<=frase[i];i++){
        for (int vocal=0;vocal<MAX_VOCALS;vocal++){
            if (vocales[vocal]==frase[i] || vocales[vocal]+32==frase[i]){//Recuerda que usamos ASCII
                vocales_cant[vocal]++;
            }
        }
    }
    int i=0;
    for (int vocal=0;vocal<MAX_VOCALS;vocal++){
        if (vocales_cant[vocal]>0){
            output[i++]=vocales[vocal];
            output[i++]=',';
        }
    }
    output[--i]='\0';
    
    printf("\nFrase: %s\nVocales en la frase [%s]\nCantidad de vocales en la frase:\n",frase,output);
    
    for(i=0;i<MAX_VOCALS;i++){
        printf("%c=%d\n",vocales[i],vocales_cant[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```